# How to add new pins in the Arduino Due

Tags: arduino-due

I want to modify (extend) g_APinDescription array defined in the variant.cpp.
It is necessary for new pin addition. I want to use PB0-PB7 ports as an external interrupts.

I tried the following code:

```
g_APinDescription = (const PinDescription *) realloc(g_APinDescription, (103 * sizeof(const PinDescription)));
```

I have a compilation errors:

> invalid use of array with unspecified bounds

I'm not C expert and don't know what is wrong here.

I want to use several pins which are unconnected on the DUE.
Usual read and write is simple to implement but if I want to use the interrupts then difficulties arrive.

Comment: Are you editing the variant or trying to modify it from within your sketch? How do you realloc a constant...?

Comment: I don't want to edit any existing files. I want to do everything from my sketch.

Comment: For mega seems it is easier:
ISR(EXT_INT0_vect)
{
}
I didn't find anything similar for due